# Code Completion with Netbean

Tags: java, netbeans

When I hit *CTRL-Space* to complete typing the function, there is a suggestion for a parameter for the method that it just filled in.  Is there key stroke that will accept that suggestion.

For example if I type *setD* and then hit *Ctrl-Space*, it will fill in the setter for *setDeliveryDate()* and *GregorianCalendar* is displayed in yellow above the parentheses.  How can I get it to fill in the *GregorianCalendar* as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the arrow key to select the autocomplete you want and then hit enter...